# Python typing error with special fields defined in inherited classes

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, mypy, solid-principles

I'm working on Makao(Macao) card game in python and try to use best practices while development.
The challenge I made to myself to make the implementation extensible, because there are many variants of that card game.
I've also introduced mypy to check annotations.

All current game data is stored in single class called "Board", below is part of that class:

```py
@dataclass
class Board:
    """
    The board is the main game state dataclass.
    It stores all data about the game.
    """

    players: Players
    deck: Deck
    discard_pile: DiscardPile
    state: AbstractGameState
    player_pauses: dict = field(default_factory=dict)
    drawn_cards_in_turn: int = 0
    winners: List[Player] = field(default_factory=list)
```

Game can run into different states e.g. battle state, normal state, rank call state etc.
I decided to define each of the state in separate class and Board class has object of the current state.
It works fine and is extensible (I can easily add new States if needed), **most of the states define its own fields**. For example below `rank_call` and `call_turns` are unique to this state:

```py
@dataclass
class RankCallState(AbstractGameState):
    """
    Rank call state.
    """

    rank_call: Rank
    call_turns: int
    name: str = field(default=RANK_CALL_STATE_NAME, init=False)
```

All changes to the Board data class are being done by actions.
Each action has access to the `Board` instance and thus also to the current `State` object.
But in actions which tries to access these specific fields from the state, mypy complains that `AbstractGameState` does not have these fields.
This is understandable of course (Board class expects AbstractGameState which doesn't have these special fields), but how can I preserve the ability to extend the system and fix that typing errors?

I have one possible solution (not ideal in my opinion) - I can just put all the special fields in the Board data class as well.
I would like to hear from you if you see other, better options to handle that.
Thank you

EDIT:
Below is an example action class (I stripped down code lines to important ones):

```py
@dataclass
class RankCallAction(AbstractPlayerCardAction):
    """
    Action to call a rank.
    """

    rank_call: Optional[Rank] = None

    @staticmethod
    def _check_if_card_is_valid(
        card: Card, top_card: Card, state: AbstractGameState
    ) -> bool:

        card_is_jack = card.rank == Rank.JACK
        suit_call_state_and_card_matching_jack = (
            state.name == SUIT_CALL_STATE_NAME and card.suit == state.suit_call
        )
        return card_is_jack and  suit_call_state_and_card_matching_jack
        
    @classmethod
    def get_single_cards_to_play(cls, hand: List[Card], board: Board) -> List[Card]:
        """
        Returns the single cards to play.
        :param hand: List of Card objects.
        :param board: Board object.
        :return: List of Card objects.
        """
        state = board.state
        top_card = board.discard_pile.top_card

        return [
            card for card in hand if cls._check_if_card_is_valid(card, top_card, state)
        ]
```

The problem is in `check_if_card_is_valid` method, specifically with `card.suit == state.suit_call` - mypy says  `Mypy: "AbstractGameState" has no attribute "suit_call"`
The `state` is taken from `Board` class and because in `Board` class, `state` field is defined as `AbstractGameState` - it causes this issue.

Comment: "But in actions which tries to access these specific fields from the state, mypy complains that AbstractGameState does not have these fields." Can you please provide an example for this?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have updated the question with the `RankCallAction` example and provided more details to the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since `Action` modifies *a specific subclass* of `AbstractGameState`, and we know which specific subclass is expected, the easiest way to get the action type-checked is to use [type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html) with `isinstance`. This allows us to derive a more precise type of the current state.

```py
@staticmethod
def _check_if_card_is_valid(
    card: Card, top_card: Card, state: AbstractGameState
) -> bool:
    # We raise an error if the state is not RankCallState,
    # guaranteeing that we only proceed when the state is valid for this action
    if not isinstance(state, RankCallState):
        raise ValueError("Current state is not RankCallState")

    # Mypy now knows that `state` must be an instance of `RankCallState`
    card_is_jack = card.rank == Rank.JACK
    suit_call_state_and_card_matching_jack = (
        state.name == SUIT_CALL_STATE_NAME and card.suit == state.suit_call
    )
    return card_is_jack and  suit_call_state_and_card_matching_jack
```

Comment: Thank you, that's another way of addressing that.
However, I thought there will be more OOP approach (requiring some refactoring).

Also, I have a question, why mypy does not narrow the type when the condition is extracted to variable like:
```is_battle_card_on_top_and_battle_ongoing = top_card in BATTLE_CARDS and isinstance(state, BattleState)
```
Then code does not type narrow to `BattleState`, but when `isinstance` statement is in direct `if`, then it's ok.